# How to run jbpm after build from source?

Tags: jbpm

After following the steps from README.md of the jBPM git repository, how I do to run the jBPM?

The `mvn clean install -DskipTests` don't generate a .war in the target or in the .m2 repository, so, this use is to embedded use only? I can run in JBoss or Wildfly, like the zip downloaded from jbpm.org?

Comment: Could you confirm which repository are building? Are you building all repositories in kie-group?  or any specific repo? and which war file are you trying to create? Try following https://github.com/kiegroup/droolsjbpm-build-bootstrap/blob/master/README.md doc for building from source code.

Comment: I am building this repo: https://github.com/kiegroup/jbpm
What I want is build the project to run in JBoss, so I want the "business-central.war", like the RHPAM has, but from jbpm.

Comment: You will have to run " droolsjbpm-build-bootstrap/script/mvn-all.sh -DskipTests clean install" to build all repos. kie-server.war would be generated at "kie-wb-common/kie-wb-common-screens/kie-wb-common-server-ui/kie-wb-common-server-ui-backend/target" and jBPM installer would be generated at "/jbpm/jbpm-installer/target".

Comment: It would be easier if you just the project you want to debug and just replace the JAR in an existing installation.

Comment: @Sudhish Nair command u gave not working. I downloaded all dependent projects. Now I want to build but don't how to do it. I read here how to build the full application using build-chain [here](https://github.com/kiegroup/droolsjbpm-build-bootstrap). Due to the large size f the project unable to run the build command as suggested.

Comment: build-chain build branch -f compilation-config.yaml -b main --fullProjectDependencyTree -p kiegroup/droolsjbpm-build-bootstrap -o /home/taiga/kiegroup --skipProjectCheckout kiegroup/kie-uberfire-extensions kiegroup/kie-soup kiegroup/lienzo-tests kiegroup/lienzo-core kiegroup/jbpm-wb kiegroup/kie-wb-playground kiegroup/kie-jpmml-integration kiegroup/jbpm-work-items kiegroup/droolsjbpm-integration kiegroup/process-migration-service kiegroup/droolsjbpm-build-bootstrap kiegroup/jbpm kiegroup/appformer kiegroup/droolsjbpm-knowledge kiegroup/drools-wb kiegroup/kie-wb-distributions kiegroup/drools

Comment: from which folder I need to run the above-posted command? Please guide me

Comment: @dinu0101 What are you trying to build exactly?